# How to partition RDF triples in Java based on subject

Tags: java, hash, rdf, hashcode, triples

For partitioning RDF triples by subject, I use String.hashCode() of the subject and put the triple in the corresponding partition. The goal is to be able to process the partitioned files in memory(processing large file may not be possible).

Now in order to have a restricted number of partitions, i do the following. Assuming that we want to have 10 partitions, out of a large RDF file:

```
    String subject; 
    partitionFileName = subject.hashCode / (Integer.MAX_VALUE/10)
```

Therefore all the triples with the same subjects will be in one partition and overall we will have 10 partitions.

Now the problem is, when the triples have different distributions, it can lead to very big or very small partitions which are undesired.

Does anybody have any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `subject.hashCode() % 10`?

Comment: Esoteric's answer is great, but here's a good read: https://github.com/gholt/ring/blob/master/BASIC_HASH_RING.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algorithm:

- Create a partition for each subject (this can be done on the fly during RDF processing)
- For each triple, assign it to a partition according to the subject and memoize the subject-partition mapping
- While number of partitions > 10, merge the two smallest partitions and update the map

Pros:

- Ensures all triples with the same subject are in the same partition
- Balanced as long as your data isn't terribly lopsided
- You don't have to use the hashcode if you don't want to

Cons:

- Additional processing time, though not an onerous amount; this is O(n * m) where n is the number of triples and m is the number of distinct subjects
- Disparate partition sizes if your data is greatly uneven, but this is unavoidable given that you want all triples with the same subject in the same partition
- You have to maintain the mapping to perform lookups against, but this is ultimately trivial to do and a constant time operation

If you don't care about keeping same-subject triples within a single partition, then just create ten buckets and fill them round-robin. O(n) and as balanced as possible.

Comment: Excellent. Conversely, if you don't care about the number of partitions but want to ensure the size of each partition is no larger than X, fill one bucket at a time and create the next bucket when the previous one is full.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the modulo to split the partitions:

```
subject.hashCode() % 10
```

will split more or less evenly across the ten partitions.

Comment: What makes you think the collection of subjects will produce an approximately even distribution of hash codes? There's no guarantee here by using the base String implementation, because the distribution is data driven. Subjects of triples are likely to have some extremely common ones and some rare ones, yielding an uneven distribution even if the hash function is even across the set of values.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Thank you for your comment. Could you think of any other solution? I do not think that there is any solution.

Comment: @javadeveloper the core of the problem is that you are partitioning by subject - where you do not actually know if such a partitioning will produce a reasonable "spread" (there might be one subject with a 10,000 triples, and one subject with only 3 in your data). If your goal is to produce a partition of reasonably evenly-sized files, you don't need to look at the subject at all.